# CSS application order

Tags: html, css, styles

I have this CSS

```
.menuPopup div {
    width: 100%;        
    padding: 5px;
}

.menuClose {
    width:10px; 
    height:10px; 
    padding:0px; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
    right:0px; 
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Which should apply to this HTML:

```
<div class="menuPopup">
    <div >A</div>
    <div >B</div>
    <div >C</div>
    <div class="menuClose">X</div>
</div>
```

When applied, the `.menuPopup div` declaration allways overrides `.menuClose`.

How can I change the order? ie. make the width of "X" `10px` instead of `100%` ?

Comment: Also, you might want to look into "CSS Specificity".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you have more selectors in the top declaration.

if you do this it should overwrite:

```
.menuPopup div.menuClose {
    width:10px; 
    height:10px; 
    padding:0px; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
    right:0px; 
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

See this article for an explanation on how css cascade priorities are handled:
http://eriestuff.blogspot.com/2007/11/css-cascade-what-defenition-takes.html

Comment: Thank's this works, however what do you mean by `more selectors`?

Comment: `Count the number of attributes, class names and pseudo-classes. The highest score wins!` never knew about that rule ! thanks again

Comment: .menuPopup div uses two. .menuPop and div. .menuClose only uses one. CSS will prioritize by selector if conflicting styles are defined. Technically .menuClose fell under the first declaration because it is also a div. So css chooses the first selector because you went through the trouble of specifying div within .menuPop... if that doesn't make sense, just trust you'll get used to it. More specific the selector, higher priority

Comment: Just to point out it would be sufficient to write .menuPopup .menuClose without the explicit div to beat the .menuPopup div rule.

Comment: @frazerjay - definitely. I just pasted it in like that to illustrate that more wins.

Comment: It's more intricate than just number of selectors. It's more like a scoring system - where each type of selector is worth a certain value. For example an Id (#myId) is worth more than a class (.myClass) as kai states, the more explicit you make the chain of selectors the more points it scores. .myBox .myClass is worth more than .myClass

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `!important` for the rule you want to be enforced.  For example:

```
.menuClose {
width:10px !important; 
height:10px !important; 
etc...
}
```

Comment: that would overwrite but it's definitely a better idea to only use !important if absolutely necessary. Simply drilling down the selector would work without closing off other cascading styles

Comment: i thought about this but it's not good practice if i remember right

Comment: While `!important` will work, it's best to figure out the CSS specificity and avoid this "hack" so to speak.

Comment: Thanks.  Learn something new every day.